# UnicodeDecodeError Python/Django application

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I'm getting this error

> UnicodeDecodeError at /select_text 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte
>   0xe7 in position 92: invalid continuation byte Request Method:    POST
>   Request URL:  http://agata.pgie.ufrgs.br/select_text Django
>   Version:  2.0.1 Exception Type:   UnicodeDecodeError Exception Value: 
>   'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 92: invalid
>   continuation byte Exception
>   Location: /home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/codecs.py
>   in decode, line 319 Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python3 Python
>   Version:  3.4.3 Python Path:   ['/home/metis/public_html/AGATA', 
>   '/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4', 
>   '/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>   '/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', 
>   '/usr/lib/python3.4',  '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
>   '/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
>   Server time:  Thu, 22 Feb 2018 12:29:51 +0000 Unicode error hint The
>   string that could not be encoded/decoded was: Varia��es
>   nvironment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://agata.pgie.ufrgs.br/select_text

Django Version: 2.0.1
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'textMining',
 'bootstrapform']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/textMining/views.py" in select_text
  59.     text_mining = TextMining(file_path, keywords)

File "/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/textMining/TextMining.py" in __init__
  15.         self.separete_file_sentences()

File "/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/textMining/TextMining.py" in separete_file_sentences
  31.             file_text = text_file.read().decode('string-escape').decode("utf-8")

File "/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/codecs.py" in decode
  319.         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /select_text
Exception Value: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 92: invalid continuation byte
```

on my Django app, already on Apache.., can't figure out what's the problem here, since I'm dealing with encoding (At least I think so..)

My code(following the sequence):

```
def select_text(request):

    book_file = request.FILES['book']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    file_name = fs.save(book_file.name, book_file)
    uploaded_file_url = fs.url(file_name)
    print(uploaded_file_url)

    keywords = [
        request.POST['keyword_1'],
        request.POST['keyword_2'],
        request.POST['keyword_3'],
    ]

    blank_optional_keywords = {
        'keyword_2' : False,
        'keyword_3' : False
    }

    if keywords[1] == "":
        blank_optional_keywords['keyword_2'] = True
    if keywords[2] == "":
        blank_optional_keywords['keyword_3'] = True

    request.session["blank_optional_keywords"] = blank_optional_keywords

    #file_name = "LivroMA4_P1_formatado(1).txt"

    #file_path = get_file_path(file_name, 'text')

    file_path = get_file_path(uploaded_file_url, 'upload')

    text_mining = TextMining(file_path, keywords)
    text_mining.get_keywords_sentences()

    sentences = text_mining._keyword_sentences

    sentences_info = generate_sentences_info(sentences)

    request.session["sentences_info"] = sentences_info

    return render(request, 'textMining/select_text.html', {'sentences_info': sentences_info})
```

The TextMining class functions:

```
class TextMining(object):
    def __init__(self, file_path, keywords):
        self._file_path = file_path
        self._keywords = keywords
        self._sentences = list()
        self._keyword_sentences = dict()

        self.lower_keywords()
        self.separete_file_sentences()
...
    def separete_file_sentences(self):
        with open(self._file_path, "r", encoding='utf-8') as text_file:
            file_text = text_file.read()
            sentences = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(file_text)

            for i in range(len(sentences)):
                if(len(sentences[i]) > 0):
                    self._sentences.append(sentences[i])
```

I've been dealing with this for a few days now, tried a lot of things, but nothing works..

urls.py (TextMining app)

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^select_text', views.select_text, name = 'select_text'),
        url(r'^edit_text', views.edit_text, name = 'edit_text'),
        url(r'^generate_aiml', views.generate_aiml, name = 'generate_aiml'),
]
```

urls.py (TextMiningProject)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('textMining.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: If possible, please click on the **Switch to copy-and-paste view** and post a proper stack trace, so it's easier for us to read the error messages

Comment: @VitorFreitas done, sorry, never saw that option on the error page kkk

Comment: Paste your urls.py here

Comment: @AstikAnand edited the post with it

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, strangely, the source of the issue was the database but Django was saying the issue was in the template at position 122 I kept removing lines from my template but Django was moving the error to the next line!. I discovered in the database that there was a UTF8 field with type TINYTEXT

```
`md` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'metadata',
```

I was copying the data from another table with "insert into table select..." statement, the source table field type was TEXT and when the data are copied some long text get truncated in the middle of UTF8 character which confused Django. The solution was to change the datatype of the field to TEXT then copy the data again.

```
`md` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'metadata',
```